# How to replace keys to values in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dictionary and the dataframe. I would like to replace keys to values in column 'x_kod'. How can I do that?

```
lookup_x_kod = {
    'BUBD01': 'budynki mieszkalne jednorodzinne',
    'BUBD02': 'budynki o dwóch mieszkaniach',
    'BUBD03': 'budynki o trzech i więcej mieszkaniach',
    'BUBD04': 'budynki zbiorowego zamieszkania',
    'BUBD05': 'budynki hoteli',
    'BUBD06': 'budynki zakwaterowania turystycznego, pozostałe',
    'BUBD07': 'budynki biurowe',
    'BUBD08': 'budynki handlowo-usługowe',
    'BUBD09': 'budynki łączności, dworców i terminali',
    'BUBD10': 'budynki garaży',
    'BUBD11': 'budynki przemysłowe',
    'BUBD12': 'zbiorniki, silosy i budynki magazynowe',
    'BUBD13': 'ogólnodostępne obiekty kulturalne',
    'BUBD14': 'budynki muzeów i bibliotek',
    'BUBD15': 'budynki szkół i instytucji badawczych',
    'BUBD16': 'budynki szpitali i zakładów opieki medycznej',
    'BUBD17': 'budynki kultury fizycznej',
    'BUBD18': 'budynki gospodarstw rolnych',
    'BUBD19': 'budynki przeznaczone do sprawowania kultu religijnego i czynności religijnych',
    'BUBD20': 'obiekty budowlane wpisane do rejestru zabytków i objęte indywidualną ochroną konserwatorską oraz nieruchome, archeologiczne dobra kultury',
    'BUBD21': 'pozostałe budynki niemieszkalne, gdzie indziej nie wymienione',
}
```

[image]

Comment: `df['x_kod'].map(lookup_x_kod)` can be work.

Comment: df['funOgolnaBudynku'] = df['funOgolnaBudynku'].map(lookup_funOgolnaBudynku), I'am getting "nan" I every record of column 'funOgolnaBudynku'. Do you know why? Can I use .map only once?

Comment: value that is not in the dict's key. It will return nan.

Comment: The value is in the dict's key.

Comment: maybe `funOgolnaBudynku` has unseen symbol, how about `df['funOgolnaBudynku'].str.strip().map`

Comment: you can only use `df['funOgolnaBudynku'] = df['funOgolnaBudynku'].map(lookup_funOgolnaBudynku)` once, because the value is changed when use map and assign to the origin column.

Comment: lookup_x_katIstnienia = {
    'Eks': 'eksploatowany',
    'Bud': 'w budowie',
    'Zns': 'zniszczony',
    'Tmc': 'tymczasowy',
    'Ncn': 'nieczynny',
}

Comment: df['x_katIstnienia'] = df['x_katIstnienia'].map(lookup_funOgolnaBudynku) / and im getting 'nan. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['x_kod'] = df['x_kod'].map(lookup_x_kod)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `look_x_kod` dictionary

```
import pandas as pd

>>> lookup_x_kod = {
...     'BUBD01': 'budynki mieszkalne jednorodzinne',
...     'BUBD02': 'budynki o dwóch mieszkaniach',
...     'BUBD03': 'budynki o trzech i więcej mieszkaniach',
...     'BUBD04': 'budynki zbiorowego zamieszkania',
...     'BUBD05': 'budynki hoteli',
...     'BUBD06': 'budynki zakwaterowania turystycznego, pozostałe',
...     'BUBD07': 'budynki biurowe',
...     'BUBD08': 'budynki handlowo-usługowe',
...     'BUBD09': 'budynki łączności, dworców i terminali',
...     'BUBD10': 'budynki garaży',
...     'BUBD11': 'budynki przemysłowe',
...     'BUBD12': 'zbiorniki, silosy i budynki magazynowe',
...     'BUBD13': 'ogólnodostępne obiekty kulturalne',
...     'BUBD14': 'budynki muzeów i bibliotek',
...     'BUBD15': 'budynki szkół i instytucji badawczych',
...     'BUBD16': 'budynki szpitali i zakładów opieki medycznej',
...     'BUBD17': 'budynki kultury fizycznej',
...     'BUBD18': 'budynki gospodarstw rolnych',
...     'BUBD19': 'budynki przeznaczone do sprawowania kultu religijnego i czynności religijnych',
...     'BUBD20': 'obiekty budowlane wpisane do rejestru zabytków i objęte indywidualną ochroną konserwatorską oraz nieruchome, archeologiczne dobra kultury',
...     'BUBD21': 'pozostałe budynki niemieszkalne, gdzie indziej nie wymienione',
... }
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=['BUBD01','BUBD01','BUBD16','BUBD04','BUBD05','BUBD12','BUBD21','BUBD10'],columns=['x_kod'])
>>> df['x_kod_value'] = df['x_kod'].apply(lambda x:lookup_x_kod[x])
>>> df
    x_kod                                        x_kod_value
0  BUBD01                   budynki mieszkalne jednorodzinne
1  BUBD01                   budynki mieszkalne jednorodzinne
2  BUBD16       budynki szpitali i zakładów opieki medycznej
3  BUBD04                    budynki zbiorowego zamieszkania
4  BUBD05                                     budynki hoteli
5  BUBD12             zbiorniki, silosy i budynki magazynowe
6  BUBD21  pozostałe budynki niemieszkalne, gdzie indziej...
7  BUBD10                                     budynki garaży
>>>
```